# How do other 2d tile-based web games record their overworld data?

Tags: 2d, turn-based, data

I'm developing a 2d (top down) tile-based strategy game that is web based. It uses PHP and a MYSQL database along with jquery. It was originally a mostly text-based game. I have since developed what I consider to be a primitive engine which handles multi-player turn processing and things like player movement are now automated.

I'm wondering how other 2d tile-based, turn-based games that are web-based, and even non-web-based, handle their game world data (terrain details, who is standing where, etc.). By "handle" i mean store and use -- not just one or the other.

My game world is essentially a sector grid of about 250,000 maptiles in total! This is simply a large database of sector information which represents several continents. Because it is turn-based I have not seen any problem with the large amount of sector information (no lag yet) but I am concerned I may be going about it the wrong way. Not all of those tiles are visible at a given time, only a small area. However, I'm aware of size limitations to database tables and already have a database that is 4gigs. How do other 2d tile-based games with large worlds record their sector information, terrain details, and how do they keep track of who is standing in a sector? My game world consists of several large continents. Is there a better, or more efficient way to record this information?

What if i decided to increase the scale of my game world and effectively increase the number of sectors in my world? 250,000 sectors sounds like a lot but it really isn't. With my current model my world is roughly 1/4th the size of our Earth. My goal is to have an Earth sized world.

Do other continent-based overworlds do this same thing? I realize a small game world would be fine with something like this but I'd like to increase the detail in my world but doing so would mean increasing (multiplying) the number of sectors and having an even larger database to contend with.

Comment: How other games do it isn't so important. Can you go into more detail about the problems you're having with your current implementation? Having performance problems? Have you profiled the code?

Comment: How other games do it IS very important as a frame of reference. Knowing how others overcome similar obstacles is extremely important. If you have no frame of reference you are working inside of a bubble without knowing if there are better or worse ways to do things outside of trial and error. I am not having any performance problems whatsoever, I'm just weary of increasing the size/detail of my game world and doubling or tripling my sector count. Could you elaborate on "profiling" the code.

Comment: Profiling is running the code through a profiler. This utility attaches to your game and accurately measures the time/resource usage for each function/line. It helps you narrow your optimization efforts. It's not so important how other games do it is because it's just one piece of the puzzle. There are lots of ways to do this type of thing, and ever more reasons to choose one over the other. Even if you knew what method someone else uses, you can't be sure of *why* they chose that method. So you first need to identify the problem you're trying to solve, before finding possible solutions.

Comment: Without knowing how another game does this type of thing I wouldn't know if other possibilities and solutions existed. It is important. Knowing more pieces of the puzzle is always a help and a useful thing. Thanks for not providing a useful comment. This question has been resolved elsewhere.

Comment: Sorry you don't see my comments as useful, my intention was for you to modify your question to help you get the help you needed. Glad you got it solved elsewhere, feel free to post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a game similar to [Pardus](http://www.pardus.at) as part of my diploma project. It has a tile-based world just like you described: hundreds of sectors (=continents), each sector is a 2D map with ~1000 tiles. There are different tile types (empty space, nebula, energy fields, asteroids etc.), there can be buildings, resources, players or monsters on each tile.

Here's the schema of my *'tile'* table and all the tables that are linked to a *tile* in some way:
[image]

The most important thing to notice here, is that each *tile* has an ID. The basic info (coordinates, sector ID etc.) are stored in the *'tile'* table. A *'player'* will just reference a *tile* by its ID. This way, I don't have to store duplicates of coordinates, tile type etc. When I want to know where a certain *player* is, I do a query like this:

```
SELECT tile.coord_x, tile.coord_y, tile.sector
FROM tile, player
WHERE tile.id = player.tile
```

You should google for the keywords **'database normalization'**. A good practice is to **normalize to [3NF (third normal form)](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/3nf.htm)**.

Comment: This seems to be what I am doing. Each sector has a unique ID and additionally there are about 20 different images (terrain types). For each sector I am recording the maptile ID. Is this what you are saying? Thanks for the look at your schema. I'll study it in more detail but for the most part it looks very identical to what I'm doing. I'll look up database normalization and 3nf today. I have never heard of that before... although from the looks of it it's something I'm already doing. I guess my main concern is the sheer number of sectors I'm working with (250,000). No performance probs yet.

Comment: Nice schema Marton. Michael 250,000 rows wouldn't be a problem in a database like Marton's. Look at how his central tile table is composed completely of number columns. Generally it's best to start with a normalized database, run profilers, and denormalize as the need arises.